# defined? in Ruby works in irb but not in my class file

Tags: ruby

I was writing a small Heap implementation and upon creating my Node class I noticed some weird behaviour. I wanted to call `defined?(x)` to ensure `x` was defined, then check if `x` was an Integer, before storing it in the Node's value class variable. In IRB I can call
`defined?(x)` and the result is nil.

However, in the class, I try this:

```
def change_value value
  @value = value if defined?(value)
end
```

and the result when I call the `change_value` with a random letter, let's say 'e', is the standard undefined local variable or method error. Again, in IRB it seems to work fine and I am wondering if I have some kind of environment issue or if this is not the 'best' way to check if value is really there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

(**Edit**: DigitalRoss has since cleaned up the question's formatting, so the comment on formatting and the initial re-write may no longer apply. I'll leave them in until I get some feedback from the OP.)

That's a nearly unreadable way to write a method and it doesn't even parse on my machine (Ruby 1.8.7).

I'm assuming you mean the following:

```
def change_value(value)
  @value = value if defined?(value)
end
```

This works fine when I call it, but it's incorrect. `nil` and undefined are two different beasts in Ruby; `value` will *always* be defined in that context because it's a declared method parameter. I suspect what you are really after is:

```
def change_value(value)
  @value = value unless value.nil?
end
```

Note that some people would simply write this as:

```
def change_value(value)
  @value = value if value
end
```

because `nil` is "falsy". However, this form conflates `nil` and `false`, so it's not a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best way to check if it's really there. If `change_value` is called without providing any parameters, you would get:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Instead, you might want to check to make sure `value` is not `nil`. Of course you can do this a variety of ways:

```
if !value.nil?
  #...
end

if value
  # this will be exeuted if value is either not `nil` or not `false`
end
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

Would it have to do with calling the method from the class instance and not the object instance?